# How to test ENUMs using JUNIT

Tags: java, junit, enums

How can I create test cases using JUNIT to test ENUMS types. Below I added my code with the enum type.

```
public class TrafficProfileExtension {
public static enum CosProfileType {
    BENIGN ("BENIGN"), 
    CUSTOMER ("CUSTOMER"), 
    FRAME ("FRAME"),
    PPCO ("PPCO"),
    STANDARD ("STANDARD"),
    W_RED ("W-RED"),
    LEGACY("LEGACY"),
    OPTIONB ("OPTIONB");

 private final String cosProfileType;

 private CosProfileType(String s) {
     cosProfileType = s;
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String otherName){
        return (otherName == null)? false:cosProfileType.equals(otherName);
    }

    public String toString(){
       return cosProfileType;
    }
  }
}
```

I created a test case for my enum `CosProfileType`, and I am getting an error on CosProfileType.How can I make this test case work?

```
@Test
   public void testAdd() {
    TrafficProfileExtension ext = new TrafficProfileExtension();
    assertEquals("FRAME", ext.CosProfileType.FRAME);

}
```

Comment: What ***functionality*** are you *trying* to test?

Comment: You are asserting that a `String` is equal to an `enum` instance. What is `ext`?

Comment: _I am getting an error on CosProfileType_ :|

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `CosProfileType` is declared `public static` it is effectively a top level class (enum) so you could do

```
assertEquals("FRAME", CosProfileType.FRAME.name());
```

Comment: Worth noting that an `enum` **is always** a static nested class - it _cannot be_ an inner class. The `static` modifier is redundant in this case...

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing and `String` to an `Enum` that will never be equal.

Try:

```
@Test
public void testAdd() {
    TrafficProfileExtension ext = new TrafficProfileExtension();
    assertEquals("FRAME", ext.CosProfileType.FRAME.toString());

}
```

Comment: Try `assertEquals("FRAME", CosProfileType.FRAME.toString());`

Answer (score 1):

```
assertEquals("FRAME", CosProfileType.FRAME.name());
```

It will work only when field and value both are same but won't wotk for below:

```
FRAME ("frame_value")
```

Better to check with

```
assertEquals("FRAME", CosProfileType.FRAME.getFieldName());
```